# Copying values from one vector to another (from book)

Tags: c++

Consider this piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    vector <int *> test;
    vector <int *> v;
    int *a = new int;
    int *b = new int;
    *a = 1;
    *b = 2;
    v.push_back (a);
    v.push_back (b);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        int n = *v[i];
        test.push_back (&n);
    }
    cout << *test[0] << " " << *test[1] << endl;
    delete a;
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem's statement is:

"Given this code, answer the following questions:

1. Why does "test" vector contain only 2's?
2. How can we change for loop to copy properly (only code inside for loop)?"

I couldn't answer any of these questions, so a little bit of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any idea of what you think `test` should contain? And what is this UB code with pointless pointers doing in a book, anyway?

Comment: the topic is pointers, so i guess it is for learning

Comment: There are better ways of teaching pointers, the least of which are programs that don't have a chance to blow up your computer.

Comment: +1 for "blowing up computer", the book is published in Turkey, so I'm not satisfied by it too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code introduces dangling pointers. The body of the loop looks like this:

```
{
    int n = *v[i];
    test.push_back (&n);
}
```

The local variable `n` loses scope as soon as the loop body ends, so the pointer `&n` is now a dangling pointer. If it happens that `test` contains only 2's, that's just what randomly came out of what is *undefined behavior*.

If you want to "properly" copy the data over to `test`, you can change the `for` loop body to this:

```
{
    int* n = new int;
    *n = *v[i];
    test.push_back (n);
}
```

Please take the "properly" with a grain of salt...

Comment: so how to change for loop?

Comment: thanks, i know that, but it is just for the purpose of learning, i wouldn't use this style anyway

Comment: Still, if this is how this book tries to teach.. if possible, get another one. Good programming habbits/style is important, which is for a great portion learned by example. There are many good books out there, take your pick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 1):

The first question is a trick question: The vector contains pointers to a variable that no longer exists, and dereferencing that could cause pretty much any output. I imagine on *some* machines and compilers it prints all `2`s however.

I can't understand what the exercise is trying to do (why does it use vectors of pointers for example) so I can't really help with how to solve the problem.

One way you could do it is by making `test` store by value:

First change the test vector to `vector <int> test;`

Then change the push_back to something like `test.push_back (n);` and finally the print statements to remove the now-unneeded `*` operators.

EDIT for comment:

First, I'm suspect of this book: It shouldn't be demonstrating undefined behavior or raw pointers to single builtin types. But you can change your loop body if you want:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
 {
     int* n = new int;
    *n = *v[i];
     test.push_back (&n);
 }
```

Note that both this will cause a memory leak unless you later `delete` those pointers, a problem that storing by value eliminates.

Comment: i can't change anything except for loop

Answer (score 1):

You push two the same pointers to `n` into `test` array. `n` equals the last element of your first array. Note that after control flow exited the loop, all pointers to `n` become invalid. So, in fact your `test` array contains invalid pointers, not pointers to 2s.

You should create a copy of each integer:

```
int* n = new int(*v[i]);
test.push_back (n);
```

Note also that you have memory leak here. Each int created using `new` should be later destroyed using `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think that the premise of the question is faulty.  The loop adds two elements to `test`, each contains the address of the automatic variable `n`, the scope of which is limited to the body of the loop.  It's not guaranteed that `n` will be allocated the same memory location in both passes through the loop, but I suppose that it's likely that most compilers will reuse the same location in both passes.

Moreover, `n` is out of scope at the output statement.  So referencing the pointers in `test` to those memory locations is undefined.  Again, there's a good chance that they will still contain the values assigned in the loop.

So, only if the same location gets reused for `n` in the second pass of the loop and that location has not been overwritten at the time the output statement is executed, will the output be "2 2".  There is no guarantee of either of these premises.

2) To get the output "1 2" without changing anything outside the loop, one could change the definition of `n` to `int& n = *v[i]`, which would be a single character change from the given code, though the end result is rather strange.

A simpler solution would be to eliminate the temporary `n` and simply `test.push_back(v[i])`.